# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `item.icon` of type `object` supplied to `FuseNavVerticalItem`, expected `string`

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a project to run a contracting company and in this project I am trying to create a Salaryscale, and I have this file that contains a set of fields

But I got this error:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `item.icon` of type `object` supplied to `FuseNavVerticalItem`, expected `string`.
```

How can I solve the problem?

This file contains several fields

file.js:

```
import PeopleAltIcon from "@material-ui/icons/PeopleAlt";
 {
        auth: authRoles.super_admin,
        id: "Users",
        title: "Users Management",
        translate: "Users",
        type: "item",
        icon: <PeopleAltIcon />,
        url: "/apps/users/all",
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using a theme called "Fuse" and this theme is React and Material UI, and in the documentation for the theme there are icons for the theme, but I did not use the icons in the theme, I used the icons on the Material UI website

And this is the previous and wrong code, as I used icons from the documentation for Material UI

```
import PeopleAltIcon from "@material-ui/icons/PeopleAlt";
 {
        auth: authRoles.super_admin,
        id: "Users",
        title: "Users Management",
        translate: "Users",
        type: "item",
        icon: <PeopleAltIcon />,
        url: "/apps/users/all",
      },
```

And I modified the previous code to become:

```
{
        auth: authRoles.super_admin,
        id: "Users",
        title: "Users Management",
        translate: "Users",
        type: "item",
        icon: "people_alt",
        url: "/apps/users/all",
      },
```

The reason for the problem is that I have in the theme icons for the Material UI, and instead of using the icons in the theme, I used the icons in the documents for the Material UI, and the error appeared to me

And this is the case for all other themes